# Observable is not subscribed after return from next activity

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have CompositeSubscription in my fragment in onActivityCreated. After I change string in EditText my code in mViewModel emit Observable.

```
    mSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    mSubscription.add(mViewModel.getMyObservableIdModelCompany()
            .observeOn(rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> { Log.e(TAG, "Error NewCashDocFragment " + throwable.getMessage());
                hideProgressBar();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> empty())
            .subscribe(this::setIdCompanyKt));
```

Method in my mViewModel

```
public Observable<List<IdCompanyKt>> getMyObservableIdModelCompany() {

    return mObservableIdModelCompany
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.computation())
            .flatMap(queryx -> mDataModel.getObservableIdModelCompany());
}
```

Link to complete fragment code https://github.com/eurosecom/samfantozzi/blob/masterAS3/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/samfantozzi/NewCashDocFragment.java

If I start Activityfragment, the code works right and I subscribe Observable. If I start startActivityForResult next Activity and I return back to Activityfragment I can not subscribe Observable.

It seems like after return my Observable is on an other thread.

Why can I not subscribe Observable after return from next Activity ?

Comment: Post some more code, where is the first snippet called from? and how do you clear the CompositeSubscription

Comment: @elmorabea first snippet is called in onActivityCreated method of fragment. It seems like after return my Observable is on other thread.

Comment: In `onDestroy` call `clear()` on the composites instead of `unsubscribe`/`dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the creating and subscribing Observable from method onActivityCreated to method onResume and unsubscribing Observable to method onPause. Observable is reinitializing by every returning from next activity.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bind();
    mSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    mSubscription.add(mViewModel.getMyObservableIdModelCompany()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> { Log.e(TAG, "Error NewCashDocFragment " + throwable.getMessage());
                hideProgressBar();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> empty())
            .subscribe(this::setIdCompanyKt));
}
```